# Pycharm venv interpreter resets at every launch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

For some reason unknown to me, everytime I startup Pycharm and open a project (Python3), the interpreter I previously setup will no longer be present. In the interpreter list, it's marked as invalid.
I then have to recreate the interpreter and reinstall the packages I need.

I also loose all settings I had (Ignored errors, spellings, etc.)

During the setup, I keep the default location (/tmp/CNN_classifier.py/venv) and default base interpreter (/usr/bin/python3.5).

Is there something I'm missing to make the interpreter permanent?

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening individual files then try setting the default settings.

File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter.

I think when you are opening individual files you are not loading the project. This sets a default interpreter so opening a file without loading the project should give it this interpreter.

If this doesn't work then open pycharm normally and select the project that you are working on.

Comment: There is no Default Settings in FIle at least in current versions. And I could not find a default settings in the general settings. Any idea where I should look?